# counting the different no: strings from a column in a DB

Tags: php, mysql

I have table with name `users` and a column in it named `source` . The column contains 3 different type of values which are strings(facebook, google, yahoo). Now I need to count how many Facebook strings, google strings & yahoo strings are present in that column.

Any easy simple way to do it using php query?

How do I get to display the number!!!!!!!!

Comment: @SashiKant ok. Can u answer how do i get the specific number for the strings...how do i display the after the below command

Comment: Have edited my query, kindle check

Comment: @SashiKant I wrote what i need actually...dint get it

Comment: Could you post some example data so we know what these strings look like? Are they comma separated lists?, etc.

Comment: @ZaneBien Its just one word strings....the column source has many rows right...so each row holds one string. I just need the no: strings of each type.

Comment: @user1424394, Got it. See my solution below.

Comment: @ZaneBien see the comment...need one main thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this solution. This gets the counts into separate columns so you can easily reference to the count of your different strings in php:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(CASE WHEN source = 'facebook' THEN 1 END) AS facebook_count,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN source = 'google' THEN 1 END) AS google_count,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN source = 'yahoo' THEN 1 END) AS yahoo_count
FROM
    users
```

**Edit**: As per your comments to this answer... On how to retrieve these values using php, something like this:

```
$sql = "
    SELECT
        COUNT(CASE WHEN source = 'facebook' THEN 1 END) AS facebook_count,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN source = 'google' THEN 1 END) AS google_count,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN source = 'yahoo' THEN 1 END) AS yahoo_count
    FROM
        users";

$social = mysql_query($sql);

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($social))
{
    echo "FB Count: {$row['facebook_count']}" . '<br />';
    echo "Google Count: {$row['google_count']}" . '<br />';
    echo "Yahoo Count: {$row['yahoo_count']}";
}
```

Comment: How do i display the no: string related to facebook for example...I just need the output command or statement to display the no: of those strings after writing the above condition. We do right something like $value=XYZ;
echo $value;

I need XYZ which displays no: facebook/google/yahoo

Comment: @user1424394 Well could you post your php code? All you need to do is reference to the column name when you iterate over the result-set in PHP. What DB interface are you using? PDO? MySQLi?

Comment: $social=mysql_query("select source, count(source) from users group by source");

MYSQL

Comment: @user1424394, see edit for example of how to retrieve the counts using php if you're using the mysql_* interface.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 Select source, count(1) from users where source like 'facebook'
```

Comment: If I need to display the no: facebook ones i.e. the no: which i've got for it...how do I do that?

Comment: see dude this is what i wrote: $social=mysql_query("select source, count(source) from users group by source");
Whats the next command to get each strings number

Answer (score 0):

```
select source, count(source) from users group by source
```

Comment: If I need to display the no: facebook ones i.e. the no: which i've got for it...how do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

If your `source` column is not an optional field then you can simply use like this,

```
select source as source_name, count(*) as counts from users group by source
```

Otherwise you can use like,

```
select source as source_name, count(source) as counts from users group by source
```

Comment: Can u answer how do i get the specific number for the strings...how do i display the number of google strings that i have

Comment: Off course the database result for above query returns an array and then you can simply display them, For example use for loop and for each display as each.source_name and each.counts